# Underscore summing values in key value pairs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following object:

```
{key: [{thing: value, stuff: value}, {thing: value, stuff: value}], key2: [{thing: value, stuff: value}, {thing: value, stuff: value}]}
```

For each key, I'd like to get either an array of only stuff values for each key or better yet a sum of stuff values for each key.  Stuff values are numbers that I want to sum. I've been at this all day and am at my wits end.

Here is the exact form of the data:
Top Level:
    `[Array[1], Array[1], Array[3], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[2], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]`

Here is Array[3]:

```
2: Array[3]
```

The first object in Array[3]:

0: Object

The contents of the object:

```
Amounts: Array[3]
Avg: 1202.38
Bill: 871.43
```

There are another dozen key value pairs in each object. I want to sum all of the "Bill" for each Array which is grouped by user already. Bill exists within each object within each array.

To get the version you see at the very top I did:

```
_.groupBy(_.flatten(BigArray),'Name');
```

I thought this would be a move in the right direction as it makes explicit who the user is since I need the total bill for each Name.

Comment: Run the following in the devtools console: `JSON.stringify(BigArray)` and copy everything between the quotes into a Code Snippet, use the Tidy button and you're done. Replace the unhelpful "Array[n]" stuff.

Comment: How do I get the BigArray into the dev tools?

Comment: I don't know. Just `console.log(JSON.stringify(BigArray))` at the point in your code when it exists and has data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

```js
var d = {
  key: [{
    thing: "a",
    stuff: 1
  }, {
    thing: "b",
    stuff: 2
  }],
  key2: [{
    thing: "a",
    stuff: 3
  }, {
    thing: "b",
    stuff: 4
  }]
};
var result = _.map(d, function(arr, key) {
  var stuffValues = _.pluck(arr, 'stuff');
  return {
    key: key,
    stuffSum: _.reduce(stuffValues, function(memo, num) {
      return memo + +num;
    }, 0)
  };
});
document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
// => [{"key":"key","stuffSum":3},{"key":"key2","stuffSum":7}]
```

```html
<script src="//underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I'd say yes. I tried a few similar things but I keep getting undefined for _.pluck(arr, 'stuff').  'stuff' is very clearly a number value smdh! and arr is an object.

Comment: If `arr` is an object, then the format shown in your question is wrong. Can you update it with a more accurate representation of the data in the exact format you are working with? Also, what version of underscoreJS are you using?

Comment: maybe i don't understand what arr is. The representation is accurate. If arr is the array of key value pairs, then that makes more sense. _.pluck(arr, 'stuff') returns undefined.

Comment: `arr` in my code is the value for each key in the top level object (`d` in my code), which should be an array of objects, according to your question.

Comment: Yes, arr is an array of objects. I can't get anything out of it so far. To be clear, using the JS console it's evident that arr is an array of vanilla objects with 'stuff' as a number at the top level.  So far I've been able to touch any of the values at the top level (tried others in case I misspelled. I feel like I'm going crazy).

Comment: Well, thanks for the help man.  I'm a rook so I probably am doing something really dumb and otherwise obvious that's holding up the process. I think you're right and I tried what you offered . . . it makes sense.  Appreciation, sincerely.

Comment: @rashadb Don't worry, we're all rookies compared to our future selves. We're all constantly learning and growing. If you want to post the exact structure of your data, rather than this abstract format, and with any confidential stuff removed, I'll be able to see where your problem lies.

Comment: I added an earlier and more detailed version of the data.  I'm less worried about proprietary than I am making something clear that you could easily understand so I can get an answer that works.